# display:table adds padding/margin in webkit browsers but not FF or IE

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit, css-tables, displaytag

I'm working on some boxes where I'm forced to using the following css on a div in order to make it look right:

display:table;

It works fine in Firefox + Internet Explorer, but I just noticed that it adds a 1px border/margin/padding in webkit browsers (Safari / Chrome), which moves the box a bit... How can I get rid of this?

I've uploaded a picture example of how it's rendered:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/examplez.jpg/

Is there a "simple way" of determining in the stylesheet whether you are using a webkit browser or not? Because then I could just add a "margin-left:-1px".. I know there is a way of determining the browsertype in jQuery, but I think it's kind of overkill for this..

Comment: I had some problems with display:table. Have you tried display: block?

Comment: display:block doesn't center the box vertically, which is why I need to use display:table :/

Comment: Checkout this link: http://d-graff.de/fricca/center.html

Comment: yes in css3 you can write the different css properties of the webkit-browsers (check css3 manual).By the way how it's appearing in firefox and IE.

Comment: Better link: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Comment: -webkit-margin-start: -1px <---- This did the trick for me..